# Override Magento Module

Tags: magento2, overrides

I am trying to override authorization.phtml located in **vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/link** .

this file contains word "**or**" that appear between **sign in or create account** header link which i like to remove.

I have created the custom theme ( luma ) and created this path .

**app/code/design/vendor/custom-luma/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/link/**

and added modified **authorization.phtml** file . but the word still there .

i guess my override path is incorrect. if i make the change to the core file , it will work but not with current override .I have tried many variation of override and Naming folders as i found in default.xml section but to no avail .  any suggestion ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your folder name is incorrect it should be vendorname_modulename like MagentoCustomer in place of module-customer.

You can see point number 9 here
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-to-create-magento-2-theme.html#9-layout-files-types-and-conventions

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
information in default.xml file provided this as template.
template ="Magento_customer/account/link" and link you provided gave me the clue as the structure of override path.
so correct path is as follow
**vendor/custom-luma/Magento_Customer/templates/account/link**
I don't know why all tutorial online making this so confusing . but learning as i go . again thanks for your help.